# Get data match from a range of number perl

Tags: perl

I have a script which loads data from file which have IP's and corresponding to that Client Name. Like below

```
XX.XX.XX.XX = ABC
xx.yy.yyy.xk = BCD
```

In a array i have a list of IP's so from above data we get the Client name for the IP's in the array .

```
my @ips = split( /\,/, $key );
  for my $ip ( @ips ) {
    $name = $hash{Client_Map}{$ip};
  }
```

Now i have range of IP's as well as normal IP's in the file in the file like

```
XX.XX.XX.0-244 = BDE
XX.XX.XY.14-44 = TEST
XX.XX.XX.XX = ABC
xx.yy.yyy.xk = BCD
```

How we can handle match these IP's in code to get the client name. For loading the file we are using `use Config::General` Perl Module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading the config hash with Config::General you need to iterate over it, look for keys that are ranges, and remove them. Use the two values from the range to insert new keys into the hash.

Perl's [range operator `..`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) is a convenient way to do that. It's also nice that [`delete`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/delete.html) returns the value for the key that was deleted.

```
my $client_map = {
    '127.0.0.1'      => 'FOO',
    'XX.XX.XX.0-244' => 'BDE',
    'XX.XX.XY.14-44' => 'TEST',
};

foreach my $ip_or_range ( keys %{$client_map} ) {
    if ( my ( $lower, $upper ) = $ip_or_range =~ m/(\d+)-(\d+)$/ ) {
        my $name = delete $client_map->{$ip_or_range};
        $ip_or_range =~ s/[^\.]+$//;
        $client_map->{ $ip_or_range . $_ } = $name for $lower .. $upper;
    }
}
```

Now the hash will look something like this.

```
\ {
    127.0.0.1      "FOO",
    XX.XX.XX.0     "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.1     "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.2     "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.3     "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.4     "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.5     "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.6     "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.7     "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.8     "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.9     "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.10    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.11    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.12    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.13    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.14    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.15    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.16    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.17    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.18    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.19    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.20    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.21    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.22    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.23    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.24    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.25    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.26    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.27    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.28    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.29    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.30    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.31    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.32    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.33    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.34    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.35    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.36    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.37    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.38    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.39    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.40    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.41    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.42    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.43    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.44    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.45    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.46    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.47    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.48    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.49    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.50    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.51    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.52    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.53    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.54    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.55    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.56    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.57    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.58    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.59    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.60    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.61    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.62    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.63    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.64    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.65    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.66    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.67    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.68    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.69    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.70    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.71    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.72    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.73    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.74    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.75    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.76    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.77    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.78    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.79    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.80    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.81    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.82    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.83    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.84    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.85    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.86    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.87    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.88    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.89    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.90    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.91    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.92    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.93    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.94    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.95    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.96    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.97    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.98    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.99    "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.100   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.101   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.102   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.103   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.104   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.105   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.106   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.107   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.108   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.109   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.110   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.111   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.112   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.113   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.114   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.115   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.116   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.117   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.118   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.119   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.120   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.121   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.122   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.123   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.124   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.125   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.126   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.127   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.128   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.129   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.130   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.131   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.132   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.133   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.134   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.135   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.136   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.137   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.138   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.139   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.140   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.141   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.142   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.143   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.144   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.145   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.146   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.147   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.148   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.149   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.150   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.151   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.152   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.153   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.154   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.155   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.156   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.157   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.158   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.159   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.160   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.161   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.162   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.163   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.164   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.165   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.166   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.167   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.168   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.169   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.170   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.171   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.172   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.173   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.174   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.175   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.176   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.177   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.178   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.179   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.180   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.181   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.182   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.183   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.184   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.185   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.186   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.187   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.188   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.189   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.190   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.191   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.192   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.193   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.194   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.195   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.196   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.197   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.198   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.199   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.200   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.201   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.202   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.203   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.204   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.205   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.206   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.207   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.208   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.209   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.210   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.211   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.212   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.213   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.214   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.215   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.216   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.217   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.218   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.219   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.220   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.221   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.222   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.223   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.224   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.225   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.226   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.227   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.228   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.229   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.230   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.231   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.232   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.233   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.234   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.235   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.236   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.237   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.238   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.239   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.240   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.241   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.242   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.243   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XX.244   "BDE",
    XX.XX.XY.14    "TEST",
    XX.XX.XY.15    "TEST",
    XX.XX.XY.16    "TEST",
    XX.XX.XY.17    "TEST",
    XX.XX.XY.18    "TEST",
    XX.XX.XY.19    "TEST",
    XX.XX.XY.20    "TEST",
    XX.XX.XY.21    "TEST",
    XX.XX.XY.22    "TEST",
    XX.XX.XY.23    "TEST",
    XX.XX.XY.24    "TEST",
    XX.XX.XY.25    "TEST",
    XX.XX.XY.26    "TEST",
    XX.XX.XY.27    "TEST",
    XX.XX.XY.28    "TEST",
    XX.XX.XY.29    "TEST",
    XX.XX.XY.30    "TEST",
    XX.XX.XY.31    "TEST",
    XX.XX.XY.32    "TEST",
    XX.XX.XY.33    "TEST",
    XX.XX.XY.34    "TEST",
    XX.XX.XY.35    "TEST",
    XX.XX.XY.36    "TEST",
    XX.XX.XY.37    "TEST",
    XX.XX.XY.38    "TEST",
    XX.XX.XY.39    "TEST",
    XX.XX.XY.40    "TEST",
    XX.XX.XY.41    "TEST",
    XX.XX.XY.42    "TEST",
    XX.XX.XY.43    "TEST",
    XX.XX.XY.44    "TEST"
}
```

Comment: @ips contains all IP's from the log i have to match it with range which is defined in the file if the log IP matches the File ip or ip range then i have to print the name

Comment: @Developer that's simple enough. Build up the full lookup hash first. It's way cheaper to do that once than to do range matching for every line.